# ASP.NET Custom web control styles Render style rules

Tags: asp.net, css, inheritance, custom-controls

I have a custom web control that inherits from ASP.NET button control. In Render method override, I rendering my own HTML output (div). The question is how I can render style attributes for that control in most correct way.

I can simply iterate over the Style collection in for / foreach loop and write it to HTMLTextWriter, but maybe .NET has a build in method that writes the style definition to htmlwriter ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the Value property of CssStyleCollection object in ASP.NET WebControl.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.cssstylecollection.value.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is the `ApplyStyle()` method:

```
var style = new Style();
style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;

var ctrl = new WebControl();
ctrl.ApplyStyle(style);
```

Comment: Not exactly...I already have a style collection as a property of WebControl. But I found the solution - CssStyleCollection has Value property that returns exactly what I need :)